# Is there any way to deploy django application to godaddy hosting?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-2.0

I have a django web application and also have godaddy hosting.Is there any way to host my django app to godaddy hosting?.My database is postgresql and here I used python 3.6 and django 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a VPS, and [Godaddy has that](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/vps-hosting), but you'll find a FAR BETTER PRICE at [digital ocean](https://m.do.co/c/f68d40d2130d) for about the same specs. I've been using them for almost a month now with the $5 plan, and I love it so far. I'll be sticking with them. And just so you know, you'll get a $10 credit if you click that link there, when compared to the $5 free credit if you didn't click it.

All you'll have to do is set the DNS at godaddy to point to digital ocean's servers, make the proper A, CNAME, and other optional records, and you'll be set. Check out the links below for that and more:

[Initial server setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04) will help a lot.

As well as [how to setup django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) on it.

And [how to Point to DigitalOcean Nameservers From Common Domain Registrars](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-point-to-digitalocean-nameservers-from-common-domain-registrars).